Is it possible to persist permission to read & autofill OTP sms via WebOTP API
I am new using WebOTP API, I've integrated it in my Angular application. As I've read from documentation, when you subscribe to the WebOTP API, each specifically formatted SMS that mobile phone will receive will trigger a native permission request flow to auto fill the form. My question is there any possibility to give this permission per domain only once and to persist this selection on future SMS so that user would allow to autofill all future SMS messages.?
I've googled through the question but, unfortunately, didn't find the same question as mine.

According to WebOTp API diagram from https://developer.chrome.com/docs/identity/web-apis/web-otp - permission request is done every time message is delivered. There is no any check for 'stored grants'.
